# entitiy framework core data filter with multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

```
var model = new CheckListCatModel();

model.Categories = checkListCategoryRepository.GetAll().ToList();
model.CheckLists = checkListRepository.GetAll().Where(p => p.isApproved && p.isHome).ToList();
```

I want to filter categories to add model.Categories by if CheckList have the id of the category in the table how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you everyone i solved like this

```
var cList = checkListRepository.GetAll().Where(p => p.isApproved && p.isHome);
        var cat = checkListCategoryRepository.GetAll();
        var model = new CheckListCatModel();
        model.CheckLists = cList.ToList();
        var query = from checkList in cList
                    join category in cat on checkList.CategoryId equals category.Id
                    select new CheckListCategory { Id = checkList.CategoryId, CategoryName = category.CategoryName };

        model.Categories = query.ToList();
        return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion, ideally, your checklist entity must have navigation properties to Category,  depending on your model. As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/querying/related-data),  you can use the Include method to specify related data to be included, and use nav prop to apply your categories filter.
If it's not possible, you can use Linq Join(...)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right and your Category Id name is `CategoryId` in the checklists table, Linq Contains command should fix your problem.

```
model.CheckLists = checkListRepository.GetAll().Where
(p => p.isApproved && p.isHome && model.Categories.Contains(p.CategoryId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `CheckLists` that have `CategotyId` in `model.Categories` like this

```cs
model.Categories = checkListCategoryRepository.GetAll().ToList();
model.CheckLists = checkListRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(p => p.isApproved && p.isHome && 
        model.Categories.Select(a => a.Id).ToList().Contains(p.CategoryId)).ToList();
```